# How do I return a nested json object with json.dumps()?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to figure out how to return a nested JSON object in Python.

I have a function that I am trying to mimic an HTTP server. The code so far is:

**1. Function**

```
def funcCustom(input_data: list):
    value = [100.23]
    return json.dumps({'stats': list(value)})
```

**2. Make a call to function**

```
my_input = [[19.0,1.0,0.0]]

predictCustom(my_input)
```

**3. Current output:**

```
'{"stats": [100.23]}'
```

My question is, how do I make my function return the following. If you notice, it is a nested JSON:

**What I want it to output:**

```
{
    "stats": {
        "val": 100.23,
        "isSet": true
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is. You have a nested dictionary you want in step 4. Why not pass that to `json.dumps`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the data and produce the desired data structure yourself. Simply with

```
def funcCustom(input_data: list):
    value = [100.23]
    return json.dumps({'stats': { 'val': value[0], 'isSet': True }})
```

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Change `return json.dumps({'stats': list(value)})`

to

```
return json.dumps({"stats": {"val": value[0], "isSet": True}})
```